# How can I create and read a cookie in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I'm trying to create and read a simple cookie in laravel but I don't understand how I can do this.

I've looked at the documentation of laravel, which normally is really solid but the cookie part confuses me.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#cookies

I don't see the code for create a cookie and it seems like the plain setcookie() isn't working.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Documentation is very much clear. What part do you not understand?

Comment: Creating a cookie would be in the 'response' docs.

Comment: @curious_coder to create a cookie in my controller do I just need to use this code "$response = new Illuminate\Http\Response('Hello World');

$response->withCookie('name', 'value', $minutes);"? What does the Hello World part do?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses

Comment: Response ("Hello World") is content  to be displayed when page is loaded. Ie when page is loaded you will get Hello World displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everything else in laravel there are several ways of setting/getting cookies.

I do this (on my controller method) so the cookie will automatically be added to the outgoing response.

```
Cookie::queue($name, $value, $minutes);
```

In order to get the cookie you can use the

```
request()->cookie($name);
```